# JavaFX Row Headers

Tags: javafx, tableview

Is there a way to have headers for each row, as well as for the top of a column?
I am using Scene Builder but am not adverse to adding code manually if need be but I do need the row headers as well as the column headers.

ie:

[image]

Comment: `ControlsFX` has an `Excel` like node: [`SpreadsheetView`](https://controlsfx.bitbucket.io/org/controlsfx/control/spreadsheet/SpreadsheetView.html).

Comment: You can, obviously, just add a specific column and style it differently; however there is no way to make it so that column doesn't scroll vertically with the other columns. As noted above, [ControlsFX](http://fxexperience.com/controlsfx/) has a [`SpreadsheetView`](https://controlsfx.bitbucket.io/org/controlsfx/control/spreadsheet/SpreadsheetView.html) which has this functionality, however I am not sure how well-maintained this is.

Comment: afaik, SpreadSheetView is available for fx8 and fx10, not for fx9 (due to a scoping accident in `VirtualContainerBase.createVirtualFlow()` ;)